# How to add a new block in child theme in PrestaShop 1.7.6?

Tags: templates, themes, prestashop-1.7

Can I extend parent template file with code

`{extends file='parent:checkout/_partials/steps/checkout-step.tpl'}`

to add a new `{block}`? If yes then how?

Or do I just need to override parent template in my child theme?

EDIT:

I want to add new block outside of any block existing in parent template.

Comment: by simply adding {block name='my_block'} ......... your html code......{/block} in your tpl template. Warning, a Block is different than Hook, what you would reach by a new Block? in a block you can't  insert a module by position manager, in an hook instead you can

Comment: @Sim1-81 adding a new block works if I add my new block in one of parent's block, please see my question edit

Comment: reed hwo bocks works on smarty templates  https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.block.tpl and https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.template.inheritance.tpl

Comment: @Sim1-81 Thx for documentation link. I think this doc is also very helpful to position child block in parent block: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.block.tpl